# Cartesian equation for $((\sin\theta)^3+\cos\theta,(\cos\theta)^3+\sin\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Can the parametric equations $x=(\sin\theta)^3+\cos\theta$ and $y=(\cos\theta)^3+\sin\theta$ be expressed as an equation with $x$ and $y$ only? If so, how can it be done?

##### Current progress

By letting $t=\sin\theta\cos\theta$, I managed to get rid of the trig functions. The equations can be converted into

\begin{align}
(x+y)^2&=(1+2t)(2-t)^2\\
(x-y)^2&=(1-2t)t^2
\end{align}

and then I'm stumped. How can I continue?

Comment: You have two cubics in $t$ that share a root, so their resultant is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find a polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that:

$$
P\left(\sin^3\theta+\cos\theta,\,\cos^3\theta+\sin\theta\right) = 0
\quad \quad \forall\,\theta \in [0,2\pi)
$$

there are at least two automated approaches.

---

Thanks to the identity:

$$
\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1
$$

it follows that:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = \sin^3\theta + \cos\theta \\
y = \cos^3\theta + \sin\theta \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
x - u^3 - v = 0 \\
y - v^3 - u = 0 \\
u^2 + v^2 - 1 = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

so we can use *Wolfram|Alpha* to select the first polynomial of a [Gröbner basis](https://tinyurl.com/2sc7346r):

```
First[GroebnerBasis[{x - u^3 - v, y - v^3 - u, u^2 + v^2 - 1}, {v, u, y, x}]]
```

from which:

$$
\small
\boxed{x^6+3 x^4 y^2-4 x^4-18 x^3 y+3 x^2 y^4+19 x^2 y^2+23 x^2-18 x y^3-20 x y+y^6-4 y^4+23 y^2-9 = 0}.
$$

---

Thanks to identities:

$$
z \equiv e^{\text{i}\,\theta},
\quad \quad
\sin\theta = \frac{z-z^{-1}}{2\,\text{i}},
\quad \quad
\cos\theta = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}
$$

it follows that:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = \sin^3\theta + \cos\theta \\
y = \cos^3\theta + \sin\theta \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
8\,x\,z^3 - \text{i}\,z^6 - (4-3\,\text{i})\,z^4 - (4+3\,\text{i})\,z^2 + \text{i} = 0 \\
8\,y\,z^3 - z^6 - (3-4\,\text{i})\,z^4 - (3+4\,\text{i})\,z^2 - 1 = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

so we can use *Wolfram|Alpha* to compute the factored [resultant](https://tinyurl.com/4d2sy5zs) with respect to $z$:

```
Factor[Resultant[8 x z^3 - I z^6 - (4 - 3 I) z^4 - (4 + 3 I) z^2 + I, 
                 8 y z^3 - z^6 - (3 - 4 I) z^4 - (3 + 4 I) z^2 - 1, z]]
```

from which:

$$
\small
\boxed{x^6+3 x^4 y^2-4 x^4-18 x^3 y+3 x^2 y^4+19 x^2 y^2+23 x^2-18 x y^3-20 x y+y^6-4 y^4+23 y^2-9 = 0}.
$$

---

Although both are well suited to a computer application, the second can be more easily applied autonomously by calculating the determinant of a matrix, for example of the [Sylvester matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvesterMatrix.html).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

An experimental answer, in need of explanations :

I used Geogebra for sketching the initial curve (green curve above). It is made of 2 symmetric arcs, one obtained for $\theta \in [0,\pi)$, the other one for $\theta \in 
 [\pi,2 \pi)$ (which doesn't come as a surprize because changing $\theta$ into $\theta + \pi$ gives two opposite points), these two parts being symmetrical with respect to line bissector $y=x$.

I had the idea to compare the first arc with the curve $(C_q)$ (featured in blue above) whose equation is :

$$ |x+1|^q+|y-1|^q=2^q$$

(generalized disks for distance $d_q$ with radius $2$).

I attempted first $q=2$, then progressively diminished the exponent till reaching an almost perfect matching with $q=1.775$.

Similar matching, of course, for the other arc, now with curve $(C'_q)$ (featured in red) with equation

$$ |x-1|^q+|y+1|^q=2^q$$

How can this almost perfect matching be explained ?

Remark : the two little "sparrowtails" deserve a specific analysis.

Comment: I give up being fully *sec* ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Maple function `eliminate()` eliminates the parameter immediately:

```
eliminate([(x + y)^2 = (1 + 2 * t) * (2 - t)^2, (x - y)^2 = (1 - 2 * t) * t^2], t);
```

$$\boxed{(x^2 + y^2)^3 - 4 x^4 - 18 x^3 y + 19 x^2 y^2 - 18 x y^3 - 4 y^4 + 23 x^2 - 20 x y + 23 y^2 - 9 = 0}$$

In terms of the coordinates $x, y$, we have: $$t = \frac{4 x^2 - 9 x y + 4 y^2 + 1}{3 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 7} .$$

Comment: May I ask you if you have an explanation about the very close similarity of this curve with the union of arcs of generalized disks I have found (see my answer) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I noticed that impressive observation when you posted it several weeks ago, and I played around with the Cartesian equation in my answer, including translating the coordinates to center the arcs at the origin, but I didn't see any immediate explanation then. I'll think on it some more and reply here if I come up with something. It's interesting enough that it could merit its own question I think.