# What is the sum $ \sum^n_{j=1} (j\ln(j))^2\,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

According to Wolfram
$$  \sum^n_{j=1} j\ln(j) = \ln(H(n)),$$
witch $H(n)$ is hyper factorial.

But for the square of the terms I didn't find any answer.
$$  \sum^n_{j=1} (j\ln(j))^2 =\,?$$
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Maybe even an approximation would be good enough!

Comment: Well, it is $\ln F(n)$ with $$
F(n) = \prod_{j = 1}^n j^{j^2 \ln j} ,
$$ and you can name this $F(n)$ whatever you like. It is of course possible to obtain asymptotic expansions for $\ln F(n)$ for large $n$.

Comment: cat is cat? @Gary

Comment: @MathFail Yes, that was my point. Even in the first case, calling it hyperfactorial does not say much about the sum.

Comment: @Gary thanks . should I delete this question ?

Comment: @kodar For your interest, $$
\sum^n_{j=1} (j\ln j)^2= \frac{{n^3 }}{3}\left( {\ln ^2 n - \frac{2}{3}\ln n + \frac{2}{9}} \right) + \frac{{n^2 }}{2}\ln ^2 n + \frac{n}{6}(\ln ^2 n + \ln n) + C +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\ln n}}{n}} \right)
$$ with $C =  - 0.06576351 \ldots$.

Comment: True, maybe it is more interesting to find the asymptotic behavior, i.e. using Euler–Maclaurin formula @Gary

Comment: @Gary this is exactly what I was looking for , can you show how do you find it ? I will edit the question for asymptotic expansions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Abel–Plana formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2) with $f(z)=(z\ln z)^2$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)\ge 0$, $z\ne0$  and $f(0):=0$, and $a=0$, one finds
$$
\sum^n_{j=1} (j\ln j)^2= \frac{{n^3 }}{3}\left( {\ln ^2 n - \frac{2}{3}\ln n + \frac{2}{9}} \right) + \frac{{n^2 }}{2}\ln ^2 n + \frac{n}{6}(\ln ^2 n + \ln n) + C +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\ln n}}{n}} \right)
$$
as $n\to+\infty$, with
$$
C = 2\pi \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^2 \ln t}}{{\mathrm{e}^{2\pi t}  - 1}}\mathrm{d}t}  = -0.06576351618742522959 \ldots \,.
$$
The error term can be replaced by an asymptotic expansion if needed, e.g., with $$
 - \frac{{2\ln n + 3}}{{360n}} + \frac{{\ln n}}{{3780n^3 }} - \frac{{12\ln n - 7}}{{151200n^5 }} +  \ldots  \,.
$$
I leave the details to the OP.

Comment: $$4\pi^2\,C=2 \zeta '(3)-(\zeta (3) (-3+2 \gamma +\log (4)+2 \log
   (\pi )))$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it can be obtained by differentiating [$(25.5.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E1).

Answer (score 1):

You could at least bound the sum
$$\int_1^n j^2 \log^2(j) \,dj < S_n=\sum_1^n j^2 \log^2(j)  <\int_1^{n+1} j^2 \log^2(j)\,dj $$ which are simple and then use Euler-MacLaurin summation to get,as an approximation
$$S_n \sim  \frac{1}{27} n^3 \left(9 \log ^2(n)-6 \log (n)+2\right)+\frac{1}{2} n^2 \log ^2(n)+$$ $$\frac{1}{6} n \log (n) (\log
   (n)+1)+C-\frac{2 \log (n)+3}{360 n}+\frac{\log (n)}{3780
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

For this level of expansion $C=-\frac{149460161}{2270268000}$ seems to be quite negligible.

For example, using $n=100$, the approximation gives
$$S_{100} \sim 6.2263685110173\times 10^6$$ while the
exact summation gives
$$S_{100}=     6.2263685110875\times 10^6$$

Comment: Claude, cheers (no connection with this question) : I have a question for you : please have a look at a recent answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4707790/305862). The question deals with parametric curve $(x=(\sin \theta)^3+\cos \theta, y=(\cos \theta)^3+\sin \theta)$ that the asker wants to transform into an implicit equation $f(x,y)=0$ . Different people have given a solution under the form of a (complicated) sixth degree equation. On my side, by chance, I find a truly excellent *approximate* solution by taking 2 pseudo-circles.  What is behind this very good matching ?